# How to be certain that an SQL QUERY was successful in Express JS

Tags: mysql, express

I want to UPDATE my database and then carry out certain functions based on whether the UPDATE was successful or not.

```
//Query DB to debit user
db.query(`UPDATE users SET wallet=newBalance WHERE userId=${iserId}`, (err, data)=>{
if(err){
return res.send(err)}

//Do something with data only if UPDATE was successful.
console.log('Update was successful');
res.send('wallet debuted Successfully')

})
}
```

I however realized that the success response was sent even when a wrong userId was provided in the query.

How do I ensure that success response is sent ONLY IF THE UPDATE actually happened?

I have tried using:

```
if(!results){res.send('Failed to debit wallet')}
else{res.send("Wallet debited Successfully"}
```

I still got the same problem

Comment: The `data` in the callback is the object that specifies what happened in the update operation. I believe you can use the data object to determine the `affectedRows`.

Comment: Unless you have database constraints that will trigger an exception in your code, your update syntax will run just fine, it just wont affect any rows. A good idea is to do your own validation prior to update. Remember that the `errors` will only show if there is an exception from the database.

Comment: Thank you. I had thought that failure to find a row was supposed to trigger an error. Thanks for the exposition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `mysql` npm package in your NodeJs project then you can use the logic below to determine what happened after running the `UPDATE` query on a given userId that you have.

```js
//Query DB to debit user
db.query(`UPDATE users SET wallet=newBalance WHERE userId=${iserId}`, (err, data) => {

  if (err) {
     return res.send(err)
  }

  console.log(data);
  
  /**
   * This is returned when update was successful
   * {
   *   "fieldCount": 0,
   *   "affectedRows": 1,
   *   "insertId": 0,
   *   "serverStatus": 2,
   *   "warningCount": 0,
   *   "message": "(Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0",
   *   "protocol41": true,
   *   "changedRows": 1
   * }
   */

   /**
    * This is returned when no matching rows are found
    * {
    *  "fieldCount": 0,
    *  "affectedRows": 0,
    *  "insertId": 0,
    *  "serverStatus": 2,
    *  "warningCount": 0,
    *  "message": "(Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0",
    *  "protocol41": true,
    *  "changedRows": 0
    * }
    */

   if (data.affectedRows === 0) {
       console.log("Nothing changed in this update");
       // Do something
   }

  // Do something with data only if UPDATE was successful.
  console.log('Update was successful');
  res.send('wallet debuted Successfully')

});
```

Another approach is to fetch the data first and check if there is anything to update.

So, you would run a fetch query like

```sql
select wallet, userId from users where userId = ?
```

Now, if the above query returns empty list, then the `userId` is invalid,
if `userId` is valid then you can check for the wallet amount and can update accordingly.

Comment: Great. Please upvote the answer as well. Thanks